# Accessing a sqlite database with multiple connections

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to access the same SQLite database from multiple instances.

I tried that from two Python shells but didn't get really consistent results in showing me new entries on the other connection. Does this actually work or was is simply a fluke (or a misunderstanding on my side)?

I was using the following code snippets:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
>>> conn.cursor().execute("SELECT * from foo").fetchall()
>>> conn.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 2)")
```

Of course I wasn't always adding new entries.

Comment: Check this about locking in sqlite3: http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not a fluke, just a misunderstanding of how the connections are being handled. From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect):

> When a database is accessed by multiple connections, and one of the
>   processes modifies the database, the SQLite database is locked until
>   that transaction is committed. The timeout parameter specifies how
>   long the connection should wait for the lock to go away until raising
>   an exception. The default for the timeout parameter is 5.0 (five
>   seconds).

In order to see the changes on other connection you will have to [`commit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.commit) the changes from your `execute()` command. Again, from the docs:

> If you don’t call this method, anything you did since the last call to
>   commit() is not visible from other database connections. If you wonder
>   why you don’t see the data you’ve written to the database, please
>   check you didn’t forget to call this method.

Comment: Ah thanks! I didn't noticed there was a separate `commit()` method available. I thought they were talking about the SQL command `COMMIT`.

Answer (score 3):

You should also include commit after any DML statements. if the autocommit property of your connection string is set to false

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
>>> conn.cursor().execute("SELECT * from foo").fetchall()
>>> conn.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, 2)")
>>> conn.commit()
```